# remove cookies when i need from visitors wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cookies, plugins

I used wordpress and w3 total cache when i install this plugin to make my site more faster and everything good but if i try to edit any Cascading Style Sheet or JavaScript files i must delete cookies and cache to results of this edit appear.
What can i do to solve this problem ? If i try to make any changes this changes will not be appear to users, Their must be waited at lest month to view this changes.

Because that i need anything to delete cookies of users when i need to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a technique called cache busting. Essentially what it is, is that your server and cache is working together and find a file on the server and in the cache with the same name. If your css/js would change name efter every edit a new css/js name would appear and thus a new request has to be made. That's cache busting you ya.

Read more about it here! https://gilbert.pellegrom.me/cache-busting-wordpress-style-css/